# AngularJS Directives for Chrome App and Android 'webview' Tags

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-chrome-app

I am in the progress of changing an existing Chrome packaged app to use Angular. So far it works well, but I am not sure how to update the UI from outside Angular, for example in response to Chrome events.

As an example, I have a webview whose current address is monitored with a loadCommit. Here is just the simplified code:

HTML fragment:

```
<p>Current url = {{url}}</p>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    // This is the inital url
    // It shows up in the HTML fragment
    $scope.url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
});
```

Event listener:

```
webview.addEventListener('loadcommit', function() {
  url = webview.src;
  //How to update Angular framework with current value of url?
}
```

How do I get access to the controller's url variable so that the UI will reflect the changes? Simply referring to a global variable in the controller does not work, like:

```
$scope.url = url;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$apply`.

From the Docs:

> ### `$apply([exp]);`
>
> `$apply()` is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of [exception handling](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler), [executing watches](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

-- [AngularJS `$rootScope` API Reference -- `$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

---

### Update

AngularJS functionality should be added to `webview` tags by using an AngularJS directive.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <webview current-src="url" id="foo" 
             src="http://stackoverflow.com/"
             style="width:640px; height:480px">
    </webview>

    <p>Current url = {{url}}</p>
</div>
```

Directive

```
app.directive("webview",function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
            var webview=elem[0];
            elem.on("loadcommit", function(e) {
                $scope.$apply(attrs.currentSrc +'='+ webview.src);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The example directive adds a `loadcommit` listener that sets the scope variable defined by the `current-src` attribute to the value of `src` property of the `webview` tag.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great solution. Frankly, I didn't even know you could set up directives on existing HTML tags (such as webview). All the examples I have seen have been for defining custom tags sucs as <my-custom-tag>. Does the $apply essentially work like an eval() with some Angular house keeping added?

Comment: `$apply()` is a method of a scope object and evaluates Angular expressions in the context of that scope. For more information on Angular expressions, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). After evaluation of the expression, `$apply` invokes a digest cycle which then updates the DOM.